# Can't export component in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to import 2 components into App.js component, but for some odd reason one of the imports causes this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
> Check the render method of `MyWebComponent`.
> This error is located at:
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by MyWebComponent)
> in MyWebComponent (created by App)

I've tried importing component both with curly brackets and without them, error stays the same.

This is the code:

MyWebComponent.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import WebView from "react-native";
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from "react-native";

const MyWebComponent = (uri) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        source={uri}
        onLoadStart={() => setVisible(true)}
        onLoadEnd={() => setVisible(false)}
      ></WebView>
      {visible && (
        <ActivityIndicator
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)",
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            jusityContent: "space-around",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            alignContent: "center",
          }}
          size="large"
        ></ActivityIndicator>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyWebComponent;
```

This component is getting imported successfully (FadeInView):

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Animated } from "react-native";

const FadeInView = (props) => {
  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [fadeAnim]);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        ...props.style,
        opacity: fadeAnim,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default FadeInView;
```

This is how I import:
App.js

```
import FadeInView from "./FadeInView";
import MyWebComponent from "./MyWebComponent";

<...>

{showFirstWeb && <MyWebComponent uri="https://www.google.com/" />}
{showSecondWeb && <MyWebComponent uri="https://www.bbc.com/" />}
```

Comment: it usually happens when you forget to the return keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not importing WebView correctly. You're missing curly braces.

Also WebView from 'react-native' is deprecated.

You should use https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview insted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! I'd also like to mention that in this case it doesn't matter whether you add curly braces or not - it works both ways.